# 'Document conversion has not been set up for the document you are trying to convert'

Tags: document-converter

I have configured the services and enabled the document conversion for the web application and I'm still getting 'Document conversion has not been set up for the document you are trying to convert'
I followed the steps on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff680117.aspx with no success, any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you done a IISRESET lately?

Comment: Yes I have @Fox, didn't help

Comment: Whats the extension of source and target of your conversion?

Comment: @Ashish It's the out-of-box docx to aspx converter